# input date onchange event not called if date is the same

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like the onchange event of my input to be called even if the current date is clicked. what's a good way to make it happen?

```js
function dateChanged(elem) {
   alert('The value is: '+ elem.value);
}
```

```html
<div>Click on the same date (1/1/2020) event doesn't get called</div>
<input type="date" value='2021-01-01' onchange="dateChanged(this);">
```

Comment: Use the `blur` event instead of `change`

Comment: @Barmar doesn't work as the control is still focused when you click on current date

Comment: Then use the `input` event.

Comment: doesn't work either

Comment: If you don't use `blur`, how should it know when you're done updating the input?

Comment: Remember, you don't have to use the datepicker, you can type the date by hand.

Comment: If you want more control, perhaps you should use a datepicker widget instead of the built-in `type="date"` input.